# Time complexity of adding a lot of new items to the back of an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, big-o

What will be the complexity of adding like `100000` elements to the end of an ArrayList which was created with a default size?

Ok, adding an element to the end of `ArrayList` will `be O(1)`, but what would be a total complexity of adding like `100 000` elements to the end?

I thought it would be `O(n)`, but some people say it should be `O(n^2)`.
What is correct and why?

Comment: Obviously it will depend on the implementation of the ArrayList (When does it grow/how often will it grow/what number does it grow to). The more it grows, the closer the complexity gets to O(n)

Comment: @Kon 100000 elements for default ArrayList in Java. new ArrayList<Integer>();

Comment: Who said it was O(n^2)?  You could ask them what they were thinking.  They might have thought you said `LinkedList`.

Comment: @DavidWallace I'll definitely ask when I meet this person)

Comment: @DavidWallace `LinkedList` in Java is a doubly-linked list with a reference to the last element, as well as the first. Adding elements to its end is constant time (hence why it bothers to implement `Deque`)

Comment: Yeah, that's true.  I spoke badly.  I was thinking "linked list" in general, rather than the specific JDK `LinkedList`.

Comment: @Ordous Even if it was a singly linked list (with a reference to the last node) it could add at the end in constant time. It just couldn't *remove* the last element in constant time while maintaining that tail-reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ArrayList`  Javadoc states:

> The add operation runs in amortized constant time, that is, adding n elements requires O(n) time.

If anyone states otherwise they better have a good reason to contradict Java creators, but as the question stands, there is really nothing to disprove, as no argument was presented. ("Some people say" is not very authoritative...).

Answer (score 1):

The only factor affecting the insertion beyond O(n) is the capacity growth. How fast does that grow? If your insert element by element the capacity is not adjusted on every insertion, but actually quite infrequently. You sacrifice space for efficiency. So if by inserting another element you hit the limit of capacity it will increase roughly by 1.5 times (in the Sun implementation). How many such adjustments would you need to do for 100K elements if you start with 10? About 25... Of these 25 only the last two resizes are comparable in size to N, so with a constant factor it is O(N).

You did not, however, specify how you would insert those items. You could preset the capacity to hold your 100K elements or use `addAll`, which I hope would do the same. Still O(N)

Comment: The answer is correct, but the line of argument isn't. As your answer reads now: "You need O(log(n)) resizes and O(n) constant-time additions, so total O(n)". However, resizes take time linear in the capacity. Hence the actual result from this argument is O(n * log(n)). You are missing the crucial part that as resizes start to take more time, they also happen less frequently.

Comment: Wait, wait wait. It IS O(n), independent of whether you preset the capacity or not. The thing is there are going to be log(n) resizes, and they are going to take 2, 2^2, 2^3... 2^log(n)-1 time (assuming doubling for easier formatting). Only the last resize takes half the time of n, others are so much smaller, that is the crucial part. If you then sum them, you get sum(i = 0..log(n)-1, 2^i) => n.

Comment: Let me think about this for a sec

Comment: You are right, it is just the last two resizes that are in total comparable to N, thus being a constant factor the overall complexity remains O(N). Will correct back